# Apache same domain multi virtual host

Tags: apache

I'm currently trying to set my Apache configuration.
I have one IP (ex: `10.10.10.10`) and one domain (ex: `www.mydomain.com`).

This server is currently hosting 2 sites and each site has his own Apache Instance with his own conf and php.ini :

`/appli/projects/project1/apache_2.4/conf/project1.conf` => Site 1

`/appli/projects/project2/apache_2.4/conf/project2.conf` => Site 2

**project1.conf** is set like that (same with 443 for SSL) :

`<VirtualHost  10.10.10.10:80>
        DocumentRoot /appli/projects/project1/apache_2.4/htdocs/project1folder/
        ServerName  mydomain.com
</virtualHost>`

**project2.conf** is set like that (same with 453 for SSL) :

`<VirtualHost  10.10.10.10:90>
        DocumentRoot /appli/projects/project2/apache_2.4/htdocs/project2folder/
        ServerName  mydomain.com
</virtualHost>`

So when I am connecting to "mydomain.com" I am going to "Site 1" but I have to hit mydomain.com:453 for accessing to "Site 2" which is not really good...

I would like to have something like that :

`mydomain.com/site1` => "Site 1" (or `site1.mydomain.com`)

`mydomain.com/site2` => "Site 2" (or `site2.mydomain.com`)

And I would like to keep the `mydomain.com` hitting the "Site 1".

Unfortunatly, because each site has his own instance of Apache, I have no idea how to set them.

Last but not the Least I would like to know if it's possible to share PHP (Apache) `SESSION` accross the multi Apache Instance or if I have to use `COOKIES` accross the domain to share informations between sites.

I don't know if it's really clear, just ask if you need more informations.

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? If you want `mydomain.com/site1` and `mydomain.com/site2`, why don't you just point `mydomain.com` to a folder containing `site1` and `site2` in two different folders? No need for multiple instances or even multiple vhosts?

Comment: Btw..  you should really remove all tags except `apache`.. .this question is purely about apache config... nothing else...

Comment: I have removed other tags. Thought it could also concern other things sorry. Do you mean I should put `Site 1` and `Site 2` inside the same Htdocs ? I felt like it was smarter to use multi Apache instance in case one was going down the other one wasn't affected...

Comment: Posted an answer with my recommendations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My recommendation is this:

**File structure:**

```
htdocs/
    site1
        ...files...
    site2
        ...files...
```

**Apache vhost:**

```
<VirtualHost  10.10.10.10:80>
    DocumentRoot /appli/projects/project1/apache_2.4/htdocs/
    ServerName  example.com
</virtualHost>
```

...and then do the same thing for the SSL-vhost.

Now you can use `http://example.com/site1` and `http://example.com/site2` and the same for https.

If you start using different ports (anything other than the defaults 80 and 443, you need to explicitly write the port names to be able to access the sites, or set up a reverse proxy (adds extra complexity with no real gain).

You can even define specific rules for `site1` and `site2` in your vhost.

**Config per site:**

```
<VirtualHost  10.10.10.10:80>
    DocumentRoot /appli/projects/project1/apache_2.4/htdocs/
    ServerName  example.com

    <Directory /appli/projects/project1/apache_2.4/htdocs/site1/>
        # Some specific vhost config...
    </Directory>

    <Directory /appli/projects/project1/apache_2.4/htdocs/site2/>
        # Some specific vhost config...
    </Directory>

</virtualHost>
```

If you want different sub domains like: `site1.example.com` and `site2.example.com`, then just do different vhosts that point to the folders directly, still using port 80 for http and port 443 for https.

Just remember that you then need to have a multi-domain-certificate or a wildcard certificate for https (since they are two different hostnames). Or you could install [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/).

Comment: It seems more cleaner with your solution. Does it will allow me to share `SESSIONS` and/or `COOKIES` between all sites ?
Also, is it possible to do something like `www.exemple.com` will go to a login page (like` www.exemple.com/login.php`) and then redirect to `www.exemple.com/site1/index.php` after connexion. and if someone try to access to `www.exemple.com/site1` or"`/site2` without being logged, it will be redirected to  `www.exemple.com/login.php`

Comment: Yes, it should work. Apache only sees it as one site.